# Change data from html page with Javascript in WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

In my `Android application`, i need to use a `WebView` for one function. But i **want translate this webpage**. So i've make a `Javascript` code for remplace `"MyValueEN"` in `"MyValueFR"` with `string.xml` but i can't use`getResources.GetString(...)`.

**Exemple of my code:**

```
String js_string = "javascript:\n" +
            "document.getElementsByClassName('Div1')[0].style.display='none';\n" +
            "document.getElementsByClassName('Div2')[0].style.display='none';void(0)" +
            "document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.split(\"MyTextToChange\").join("+ getResources().getString(R.string.MyTextToChange) + ");void(0);"; //It's here the error
```

When i call `getResources().getString(R.string.MyTextToChange")`, i've got an error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

Can i use `getRessources()` in `Javascript` code ? Did i have do an error ? Or i need use another function ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to initialise

```
getResources().getString(R.string.MyTextToChange)
```

inside onCreate, incase you initialised it outside